# facebook messenger developer api: How to send text , hyperlink and image in a single message

Tags: facebook

I have explored facebook developer apis where we can send message as text or attachment. And attachment of type image, audio etc. But not getting the way where I can send a single message having text, hyperlink and image or the combination of text and hyperlink.

For example:
I am working at https://www.google.com and <some_image_url>